# Q Promise Equivalent of BlueBird Promise.Bind()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, bluebird

Few questions, does Q have a `bind()` method as seen in [BlueBird API](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise) and this slide [JavaScript Promises ~Kerrick Long](https://speakerdeck.com/kerrick/javascript-promises-thinking-sync-in-an-async-world?slide=65)? Is it part of the Core Promise/A+ Spec? If not, is there a polyfill or workaround for it?

Comment: Q implements the Promise/A+ spec, so if it doesn't do it, it's probably non-standard.

Comment: Is there a shim for Q to set `this` within promises?

Comment: @tadman Q implements a lot of stuff that's not in the Promises/A+ spec.

Comment: In that slide `.bind` isn't being called on the promise but on the function

Comment: @Esailija oh shoot. you're right. my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the Promises/A+ spec only specifies how `.then` works, so `.bind` is not a part of the Promises/A+ spec. In fact Promises/A+ specifies that the `this` value behaves like a normal function call and promises are not bound - Bluebird gets around this limitation by returning a BoundPromise which is not a regular promise and interops seamlessly with other promise libraries.

There is no equivalent Q feature, once ES6 lands you'll be able to use the "fat arrow" `=>` in order to lexically bind the scope in `then` chains:

```
this.x = 15;
Q().then(() => console.log(this.x)) // always logs 15
```

Generally speaking, this is one of many features Bluebird has over Q, there is no obvious way to 'shim it in' since it changes the behavior of `.then` - you'd have to override `.then` in Q promises and effectively create a wrapper over the whole library to accomplish that.